# Upgrading application - desktop icons - Inno

Tags: inno-setup

If a user has [Star Dock Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) installed and they have moved the desktop icon into one of the fence panels, I find that whilst the short-cut will get removed during the upgrade it is then just re-inserted back on the desktop and I have to drag it back into the fence panel.

Is there some way we can keep it in the same fence panel or is this over complicated to detect on the target PC?

So, in my script I have:

```
Name: "{autodesktop}\Meeting Schedule Assistant"; \
         Filename: {app}\MeetSchedAssist.exe; Tasks: desktopicon;
```

Here it is in a fence:

[image: Fence]

According to the icon properties it is desk a desktop short-cut, even though it is inside a Stardock Fence:

[image: Icon Properties]

So it is a shame that the new one does not stay in the same place. I don't want to use the `uninsneveruninstall` flag if I can help it.

Comment: *"removed during the upgrade"* - What exactly happens? Is the shortcut simply overwritten by the installer? Or do you do a complete uninstallation during the upgrade (based on your reference `uninsneveruninstall`)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl All I am saying is that the "icon" is no longer inside the fence. I don't specifically do anything with the icon beyond standard Inno behaviour. But I an answer now ...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I referred to `uninsneveruninstall`in the question because of the suggestion in the first answer. However, Stardock have explains what a user can do to prevent this issue so I have added my own answer with this explanation for others benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been provided with an answer [here](https://forums.stardock.com/495616/knowing-what-fence-a-icon-is-in#3753263). No changes are required to the Inno Setup script.

Rather, the user can make a specific change to the Star Dock Fences. It has to do with **Name-based rules**:

[image: Stardock Fences Properties]

By using criteria you can isolate a short-cut and tell it which fence panel it should belong too.

To quote the aforementioned link:

> You can setup a **fence** which has a **name rules** set to it. Usually any program will still use its **original name** whenever it upgrades. So if you set the name rules it will always be **moved** to that **specified fence** when it **upgrades**.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup just place a shortcut on desktop because this is specified in the configuration file. If you want to place on different locations, add them to the configuration.

You can read [this guide](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection) to learn more about icons/shortcuts.

About avoiding shortcut being moved to desktop, you probably can't because Inno identifies that there's no shortcut on desktop. Anyways, you can avoid Inno Setup from changing any shortcut.
You can use the flag: `uninsneveruninstall`.

This answer might help you: [Renaming/replacing ShortCut During Inno Setup Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336082/renaming-replacing-shortcut-during-inno-setup-installation)

If you don't want to use `uninsneveruninstall` flag, i suggest you try to add version to shortcut's name.

E.g. `Name: "{autodesktop}\Meeting Schedule Assistant 1.0"; \`

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840710/11578778) explains.

Comment: I don't really want to use the `uninsneveruninstall` flag. I appreciate your answer though.